# Show that limit of nets/sequence is unique in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I've seen proofs on sequences but not for nets.
Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is any directed set. Where $<x_\alpha>_{\alpha \in A}$ is a net in $X$ that converge to some limits $x,y \in X$. Then, for any neighborhood $N_x,N_y\in X$ of $x,y$ respectively, there exists $\beta_1,\beta_2 \in A$ such that $x_\alpha \in N_x$ , $x_\alpha \in N_y$. Then by definition of a directed set, there exists $\beta\in A$ such that $\beta\succ \beta_1$ and $\beta \succ \beta_2$. Then we have $x_\alpha \in N_x \cap N_y$, for all $\alpha \succ \beta$. Now, assume that $x\neq y$, then there exist disjoint open sets $U_x, V_y$ containing $x,y$ respectively. This contradicts the existence of a $\beta \in A$ where $x_\alpha \in U_x\cap V_y$ because they are disjoint by our assumption. Hence, $x=y$.

since nets are a generalized version of sequence, I would assume I don't need to show this is true for sequences again.

Comment: You gave a correct proof. But what is your question?

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for the comment! I just wanted to verify my proof also, do I need to show the case for a sequence?

Comment: No, sequences are special nets.